# I'd like to see the up- and down-votes of my posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The StackExchange sites make great deal about hiding up- and downvotes since that information is given as a privilege.

I don't understand however why that information is still hidden in *my* posts.

As a newbie on this website, for instance, I posted a question<sup>[1]</sup> and I can tell that at the moment of writing, it has a score of 3, with 5 upvotes and 2 downvotes, yet I'm largely under [the 1000 rep threshold required to see that information](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). What I did to know that is nothing easier than going on my reputation change tab and saw a total of 5 times upvote on that question and 2 downvotes, so the information is present.

Since it's present, it's a bit shady to get it, I suggest that anyone could see the full score of their posts (up- and down-votes) without earning any privileges. Seeing the full score of others' posts should still be acquired by reputation gain as it's currently done.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>The question is irrelevant in this topic and I don't care about more votes, so... no link.</sub></sup>

Comment: This is something you'd really need to request on [Meta.SE]. There's nothing we can do about it here. They do explain **why** it's not possible for newer users [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69852/why-is-it-a-privilege-to-view-vote-counts).

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269354/why-are-users-with-less-than-1000-rep-unable-to-see-vote-counts)'s a more recent version of the question with a similar answer from one of the SE staff.

Comment: Since this isn't privileged site information, you could always just ask someone in [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) to look for you. They'd probably get p*ssed off if you asked for loads, but I'm sure they'd be happy to do one or two. I'd do it myself, but I'm [too cool for chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/105167/richard)

Comment: Try the [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](http://stackapps.com/q/3082) user script or browser extension.

Answer (score 5):

The Established user privilege is standardized throughout the stack exchange network. For whatever reason, SE believes that you should have 1000 rep on a site to see *any* Up/Down vote stats. It's not a privilege that can be changed on a site by site basis.

If you want this to change, the first step would be to ask on http://Meta.Stackexchange.com, as this is network wise.

Whether it be a universal "let me see votes on mine" right away or a more general "let me see votes on mine if I have the Established User Privilege on at least one site" type deal, there is where it would be voted upon and answered as possible or not.